# VF Page on-click events for HTML elements

Tags: visualforce, event, onclick, dom

I have a checkbox on my VF page, with the label in a `<TD>` element of the table, and the checkbox in a `<TD>` element next to it like this:

```
<tr>
       <td class="LeftColumnTop W50" title="{!$ObjectType.Request_for_System_Change__c.fields.BOC_dormant_account__c.inlineHelpText}"
        onclick="checkIt('inMailshot_BOC_dormant_account__c')">
        <font class="MainPanelFont">
                <apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.Request_for_System_Change__c.fields.BOC_dormant_account__c.Label}"/>
                <apex:actionFunction name="onclick" action="checkIt('inMailshot_BOC_dormant_account__c')"/>
            </font>
       </td> 
        <td class="RightColumnTop W50" title="{!$ObjectType.Request_for_System_Change__c.fields.BOC_dormant_account__c.inlineHelpText}">                                                                    
            <div class="Mandatory">
                <apex:inputCheckbox styleClass="MainPanelFont"
                    id="inMailshot_BOC_dormant_account__c" 
                    value="{!sObjectRFC.BOC_dormant_account__c}"/>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

For extra usability  I'd like to have a click event on the `<apex:outputLabel value` **or the `<TD>` container** that will toggle the *Checked/unchecked* state of the checkbox. This will enable the user to just click the label for the checkbox to change it's value...

I have this method in a `<SCRIPT>` tag on the page:

```
function checkIt(string elementId){
    alert("checkIt" + elementId);
    if (document.getElementById(elementId).checked==true){
        document.getElementById(elementId).checked=false;
    }else {
        document.getElementById(elementId).checked==true;
    }
}
```

but unfortunately, even though it compiles and saves ok, the event is not being raised (no alert or anything)

What is the correct way to do this in a VF page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple way use `for` attribute of `apex:ouputlabel` and pass the id

```
<apex:outputLabel value="Checkbox" for="theCheckbox"/>
<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!inputValue}" id="theCheckbox"/>
```

Let me know if this solved your problem or not

Comment: another `DOH` moment, I used to use this in my classic ASP and DMTL DOM all the time...thanks!